# Angular FullCalendar events array refresh

Tags: angular, events, frontend, fullcalendar

I implemented a project in Angular with fullcalendar, where I get the events array from a BackEnd server and create a JSON array in Angular.
When I update this, there is no way I can set it to see the new event without reloading. How can I do this?

CalendarOptions declaration:

```
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timegridPlugin],
    displayEventTime: true,
    editable: true,
    lazyFetching: false,
    nowIndicator: true,
    eventClick: this.eventClick.bind(this),
    dateClick: this.dateClick.bind(this), // this line
  }
```

Calendar in html:

```
<full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions" #mycal></full-calendar>
```

New event add to Json array:

```
    this.eventService.create(this.newEvent).subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.eventsJson.push({title: this.newEvent.name, start:this.newEvent.startTime})
      }
```

I've tried all kinds of things, I just can't make it work. I tried to reference #mycal and tried to update it from JavaScript.

Full code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit{

  @ViewChild("createModal", {static: true}) createModal: NgbModal

  actualDay:any;
  events:Array<EventDto> = new Array<EventDto>();
  eventsJson:any[] = [];
  newEvent:EventDto = new EventDto;

  constructor(private activeModal:NgbModal, private auth:AuthenticationService, private eventService:EventService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllEvents();
  }
  
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timegridPlugin],
    displayEventTime: true,
    editable: true,
    lazyFetching: false,
    nowIndicator: true,
    eventClick: this.eventClick.bind(this),
    dateClick: this.dateClick.bind(this), // this line
  }

  dateClick(arg:any) {
    this.actualDay = arg.dateStr;
    this.create()
  }

  eventClick(arg:any){
    //modal view
    console.log(arg)
  }

  createEvent(){
    this.eventService.create(this.newEvent).subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.eventsJson.push({title: this.newEvent.name, start:this.newEvent.startTime})
        this.newEvent = new EventDto();
        this.close();
      },
      error: (error) => {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: error.error[Object.keys(error.error)[0]],
        });
      }
    })
  }

  create(){
    this.activeModal.open(this.createModal, {size: "md", centered: true});
  }

  close(){
    this.activeModal.dismissAll();
  }

  getAllEvents(){
    this.eventService.getAllByCompany().subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.events = response;
        this.events.forEach(event => {
          this.eventsJson.push({title: event.name, start:event.startTime})
        });
        this.calendarOptions.events = this.eventsJson;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.events = [];
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more code is hard to say, but with what I see I'm guessing that the problem is the full-calendar component... Maybe the ngOnChanges is not properly implemented or not used at all...
If you update the value of calendarOptions as the component is already initialised it does not go again thru the initialisation code... it's the ngOnChanges that get's triggered.

In the code you show I also do not see how you pass the data (eventsJson) to the calendar...

AFTER QUESTION WAS UPDATED WIDTH FULL CODE:

Just add

```
this.calendarOptions.events = this.eventsJson;
```

after push the event to eventJson

```
createEvent(){
    this.eventService.create(this.newEvent).subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        this.eventsJson.push({title: this.newEvent.name, start:this.newEvent.startTime})
   --->         this.calendarOptions.events = this.eventsJson;
```

Comment: I don't use ngOnChanges anywhere

Comment: if you post a more complete code sample I can help with that...

Comment: The new event is added via its own Modal and added to the database via the backend. I need this again and I need to update it somehow.

Comment: Added full code to original post